# How do I create a custom class for the general restful methods, which can be extended to the controllers?

Tags: laravel-5

I noticed that I been writing the same lines of code(index, store, show, update, destroy) for the following controllers, except for the model name where we query the data.

ItemsController, MeasuresController

How do I extract the base functions index, store, show, update, destroy to another class say 'RestfulMethods' and show how pass the model to the 'RestfulMethods' class, which extending to ItemsController or MeasuresController?

Comment: Simply Define your own basecontroller and extend it. However, you will probably overwrite a lot of stuff. Ofcourse at the very beginning of a project you often have the basic restful controllers, however during development you will adapt minor things which will force you to overrite it

Comment: Thanks @FrankProvost. In that case how do I pass the model to the base controller?

Comment: The most easy way i can think of is referencing the BaseModel in the BaseController - so basically defining a default and then overwrite it in your Extending Controller